# rxjs - buffer emitted values until other observable emits, then emit as normal

Tags: rxjs

I am building a logger object that asynchronously obtains the IP address and then logs all values with this IP address. It must start collecting logs as early as it is instantiated, but emit them  only after the IP address has been obtained; and after that it should emit as normal.

Here is my class:

```
class LoggerService {
  constructor() {
    let thisIp;
    const getIp = Observable.create(function(observer) {
      // doing it with a timeout to emulate bad network
      setTimeout(() => {
        fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json').then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
          thisIp = response.ip;
          console.log('fetched IP: ', thisIp);
          observer.next(response.ip);
          observer.complete();
        });
      }, 5000)
    });
    // this is where I plan to buffer logs until IP is obtained
    this.logStream = new Subject().pipe(buffer(getIp));
    // for starters - just log to the console with the IP address
    this.logStream.subscribe((value) => console.log(thisIp, value));

  }

  emit = (message) => this.logStream.next(message);
}
```

But it does not work as I need; it does output all buffered values as an array but stops emitting them after the IP has been obtained:

```
const logger = new LoggerService();


setInterval(() => {
  logger.emit('Hey ' + Math.random())
}, 1000);

// I get five messages and that's it
```

How do I make it emit my values even after buffering?

Comment: have you looked at a replaySubject instead of a subject? Sounds like you might be trying to reinvent a replaySubject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

Looking back at this a year and a half later, I notice combineLatest/of aren't necessary; we can simply pipe the ip observable and map it to the desired shape.  Here's how I would do it today:

```js
export class LoggerService {
  private messages$ = new Subject<string>();

  private formattedMessages$ = this.messages$.pipe(
    mergeMap(message => this.service.ipAddress$.pipe(
      map(ip => `[${ip}] ${message}`)
    ))
  );

  constructor(private service: GenericService) { 
    this.formattedMessages$.subscribe(
      message => console.log(message) // actual logging logic goes here...
    );
  }

  public log(message: string) {
    this.messages$.next(message);
  }
}
```

---

#### Original Answer

You don't need to "buffer" the values per se, but you can rather create a stream that depends on the async `ipAddress$`, so the value won't get emitted until the ip address had been emitted. [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) will work well for this purpose.

Let's give the `LoggerService` a message stream called `message$` and a simple `log()` method that pushes the provided string through this stream.

We can construct a stream of `messagesWithIpAddresses$` that use `combineLatest` to create an observable that emits the provided message along with the `ipAddress$`, but only after both have actually emitted a value.

```
export class LoggerService {
  private messages$ = new Subject<string>();

  public log(message: string): void {
    this.messages$.next(message);
  }

  constructor(service: GenericService) { 

    const messagesWithIpAddresses$ = this.messages$.pipe(
      mergeMap(message => combineLatest(service.ipAddress$, of(message)))
    );

    messagesWithIpAddresses$.subscribe(
      ([ip, message]) => {
        // actual logging logic would go here...
        console.log(`[${ip}] ${message}`);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Since `of(message)` will emit immediately, we will just be waiting for `ipAddress$`.  But, if a value has already been emitted, then it too will be immediate.

Check out this working [`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-async-logger?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogger.service.ts)

[image: screen cast sample]

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: below answer won't work. After viewing [buffer documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffer)
your logger Subject() still won't emit anymore messages because it fires only when getIp fires. In your code, getIp fires only once, after the http request.

I think we need more details of what you want to achieve in order to propose a correct rxjs pipeline.

---

I would remove this line

```
observer.complete();  // remove it
```

That signals the subscriptor the stream is over, that's why you are not receiving any messages more.